# Default parameter specifiers are not permitted in c# desktop application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, .net-2.0

```
private string formatSizeBinary(Int64 size, Int32 decimals = 2)
        {
            string[] sizes = { "Bytes", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB", "ZB", "YB" };
            double formattedSize = size;
            Int32 sizeIndex = 0;
            while (formattedSize >= 1024 & sizeIndex < sizes.Length)
            {
                formattedSize /= 1024;
                sizeIndex += 1;
            }
            return string.Format("{0} {1}", Math.Round(formattedSize, decimals).ToString(), sizes[sizeIndex]);
        }
```

I got this

> "Default parameter specifiers are not permitted"

error on `"Int32 decimals = 2"`

Comment: Optional parameters in C# were only introduced in C# 2010 (and VS2010).  If (as your tag suggests) you're using .NET 2.0 and VS2008 then the error message is pretty much self explanatory.  What's your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your code looks fine to me but [`Optional parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) come with Visual Studio 2010 (and probably .NET 4.0 framework)

> Visual C# 2010 introduces named and optional arguments

You need a method like;

```
private string formatSizeBinary(Int64 size, Int32 decimals, int value)
        {
            decimals = value;
            string[] sizes = { "Bytes", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB", "ZB", "YB" };
            double formattedSize = size;
            Int32 sizeIndex = 0;
            while (formattedSize >= 1024 & sizeIndex < sizes.Length)
            {
                formattedSize /= 1024;
                sizeIndex += 1;
            }
            return string.Format("{0} {1}", Math.Round(formattedSize, decimals).ToString(), sizes[sizeIndex]);
        }
```

Then you can call it which value you want;

```
formatSizeBinary(yoursize, decimals, 2);
formatSizeBinary(yoursize, decimals, 3);
formatSizeBinary(yoursize, decimals, 4);
```

Comment: _Default parameters are not supported in C#_ This is **wrong**.

Comment: if i want to pass decimals=3 than what should i do ?

Comment: it's write but my question is pass other value than what i should do ?